# Calculating expected value of $E[x(t)x(t+\tau)]$

Tags: expected-value

Assuming $x(t)$ is a time invariant function. How do I calculate the expected value of $E[x(t)\,x(t+\tau)]$?

Is calcuating it as follow correct?

\begin{align}
E[x(t)\,x(t+\tau)] &= E[x(t)] \cdot E[x(t + \tau)] \\
                 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}z\,f_Z(z)\,dz \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(z - \tau)\,f_Z(z - \tau)\,dz
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand why you would write $x(t),$ surely a time-varying function, and then call it a time invariant function. Did you mean to say a periodic function? Also, you should not use the function name $x$ as the dummy variable of integration $dx.$

Comment: What I meant is like its statistical properties do not change over time. For example, ideally, a lottery machine the properties of its random number generator are not a function of when the machine is activated.

Comment: So, e.g., its mean and variance are time invariant? Fair enough. Are you computing the expectation w.r.t. $t$ or $\tau$ or both? It looks like you're doing just $t.$ In that case, I would probably write $$E[x(t)\,x(t+\tau)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\,x(t+\tau)\,f_X(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: The calculation in the question is correct provided $x(t)$ and $x(t+\tau)$ are independent random variables for any $t$ and $\tau.$  That is (loosely) a form of "white noise."  Most time series do not enjoy this property.